# How do I find the function derivative $(\delta/\delta \phi) (\partial_\mu \phi)$?

Tags: field-theory, differentiation, mathematics, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

The question is simple: How do I find the function derivative of $$(\delta/\delta \phi(x)) (\partial_\mu \phi(x))~?$$ As far as I can tell, I cannot use any of the standard computational rules for the functional derivative.

Comment: $\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}$ commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\mu}$.

Comment: So the answer is the Heavyside step function?

Comment: Nope. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: $\partial_\mu (\delta\phi(x) /\delta \phi(x)) = \partial_\mu \delta^{(4)}(0) = \partial_\mu \infty = \infty$?

Comment: Hi @Marius Jonsson : Is this taken from some reference? Which page?

Comment: You want $(\delta / \delta \phi(y))(\partial_x \phi(x)) = \partial_x \delta(x-y)$. (Rather perversely, some people will drop all the position arguments and write "$\delta(\partial \phi)/\delta \phi = \partial$" or something weird like that.)

Comment: But here, x = y, so it is $\partial_\mu \delta(0)$ which is $\delta(0) \partial_\mu = \infty \partial_\mu$, by your argument?

Comment: @MariusJonsson No, it means that writing it with $x = y$ is wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $\frac{\delta \partial_\mu\phi(y)}{\delta \phi(y)}$ is mathematically **meaningless**.

By definition, given a functional $F$  associating reals (or, more generally, complex numbers)  $F[\phi]$ to smooth functions $\phi$, we say that the **distribution**  $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi(x)}$ is the **functional derivative** of $F$, if 
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} F[\phi + \alpha f] = \int \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi(x)} f(x) dx$$
for every compactly-supported smooth function $f$.

In the considered case, one has to compute the functional derivative of the functional $F$ associating $\partial_\mu \phi(y)$ to $\phi$, i.e., 
$$\partial_\mu \phi(y) := \int \partial_\mu \phi(x) \delta(x-y) dx\:.$$
We have
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} F[\phi + \alpha f] =
\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0}  \int  \partial_\mu (\phi(x)+ \alpha f(x)) \delta(x-y) dx =  \int  \partial_\mu f(x) \delta(x-y) dx$$ $$= -\int   f(x) \partial_\mu\delta(x-y) dx\:.$$
We conclude that
$$\frac{\delta \partial_\mu\phi(y)}{\delta \phi(x)} = - \partial^{(x)}_\mu\delta(x-y) =  \partial^{(y)}_\mu\delta(x-y)\:. $$
So $\frac{\delta }{\delta \phi(x)}$  and $\partial^{(y)}_\mu$ commute as said by @AccidentalFourierTransform.

In summary, $\frac{\delta \partial_\mu\phi(y)}{\delta \phi(y)}$ is **not** defined because *the value at a fixed point of a non-regular distribution has no meaning.*

Comment: +1 I would like to mention the following: if we were to insist that we want that expression evaluated at $x=y$ ("in a formal sense" e.g., with some regularisation scheme in mind), then one may argue that the expression vanishes, inasmuch as the derivative of the Dirac delta is odd.

Comment: Right, indeed:  *ex falso quodlibet*

Answer (score 0):

1. As correctly pointed out in the answer by Valter Moretti, it is mathematically ill-defined to apply (the traditional definition of) the [functional/variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) (FD)
   $$ \frac{\delta {\cal L}(x)}{\delta\phi^{\alpha} (x)}  \tag{1}$$
   to the same spacetime point.
2. However, it is very common to introduce a 'same-spacetime' FD as
   $$ \frac{\delta {\cal L}(x)}{\delta\phi^{\alpha} (x)}~:=~ 
   \frac{\partial{\cal L}(x) }{\partial\phi^{\alpha} (x)} - d_{\mu} \left(\frac{\partial{\cal L}(x) }{\partial\partial_{\mu}\phi^{\alpha} (x)} \right)+\ldots. \tag{2} $$
   which obscures/betrays its variational origin, but is often used for notational convenience.
   (The ellipsis $\ldots$ in eq. (2) denotes possible contributions from higher-order spacetime derivatives.) See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358417/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166696/2451), & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123481/2451) Phys.SE posts.

   If we interpret OP's expression via eq. (2), then OP's Lagrangian density ${\cal L}=\partial_{\mu} \phi$ is a total space-time derivative, so that OP's 'same-spacetime' FD vanishes, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451) Phys.SE post.